# SharePoint 2013: Provide a link on Parent list for Feedback form (Child list) for Items in Parent list

Tags: 2013

I have a Request List (custom List). User needs to fill  a request and once request is done he can come on the list and provide feedback for that list item. 
I want to give a link of Feedback list new form for each item in 'Request List'. When user click on Feedback link, he can submit his feedback for that particular "Request List Item'.
I have created a child list (Feedback List). Looking for pointers to achieve rest of the functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

When a request is saved in the Request List, you should be able to populate a field in the request item with a link to the new form of feedback list new form. A simple workflow or an event receiver can do this.

You should also have a lookup field in the feedback list that points to the key field in request list so that feedback items for a request can be related. 
You might have to update the feedback list form automatically with look up value when it first opens.

Not sure what your exact requirement is but you might not be able to see a comprehensive view of request and feedback unless you do some reporting or export excel and join the related items.